# Alineación de Campo en Grid Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

Tenemos una tabla y se muestran los valores que se extraen de la base de datos Mysql. Los campos son solo tres para esta tabla (Fecha, Abono y Saldo). Mi problema es que no se la forma de alinear a la derecha los campos numéricos de Abono y Saldo (con los títulos no hay problema, solo con los valores que llegan de la bd).

Adjunto las dos funciones que realizan el proceso.

Muchas gracias.

```py
def mostrarTransacciones():
    miConexion = pymysql.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user="root", password="", db="pagospymysql")
    miCursor = miConexion.cursor()
    
    registros=grilla3.get_children()
    for elemento in registros:
        grilla3.delete(elemento)

    try:
        
        sql=("SELECT * FROM transacciones WHERE obligacion= '"+obligacion.get()+"'")
        miCursor.execute(sql)

        for row in miCursor:
            grilla3.insert("",0,text=row[1], values=('{:,}'.format(row[2]),'{:,}'.format(row[3])))
        
    except:
        pass

def tablaTransacciones():

    ventanaTransacciones=LabelFrame(ventanaPagos)
    ventanaTransacciones.pack()
    ventanaTransacciones.place(x=900, y=40, width=300, height=160)

    global grilla3

    grilla3=ttk.Treeview(ventanaTransacciones, height=7, columns=('#0','#1'))
    grilla3.grid(row=0, column=0)

    grilla3.heading('#0', text="Fecha", anchor=CENTER)
    grilla3.column('#0', width=80)
    grilla3.heading('#1', text="Abono", anchor=CENTER)
    grilla3.column('#1', width=100)
    grilla3.heading('#2', text="Saldo", anchor=CENTER)
    grilla3.column('#2', width=100)

    b13=Button(ventanaPagos, text="Transacciones", command=mostrarTransacciones)
    b13.place(x=1000, y=10)

    mostrarTransacciones()
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el argumento [anchor](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ttk.html#ttk.Treeview.column) del método column del treeview:

```
grilla3.column('#1', width=100, anchor=E)
```

Cito la documentación por si el link se cae:

> anchor: One of the standard Tk anchor values. Specifies how the text
> in this column should be aligned with respect to the cell.

Que traducido por el traductor de google y revisado por mi es:

> anchor: Uno de los valores estándar de ancla Tk. Especifica cómo debe
> alinearse el texto de esta columna con respecto a la celda.

Perdón por lo del "ancla Tk", sinceramente no se que palabra del español sería la correcta.

Comment: No se si es correcto, pero quiero notificar que la respuesta me funcionó perfecto.

Comment: Gracias por avisarme! No se que opina el resto de la comunidad, pero yo opino que está bien que lo aclares, ya que siento curiosidad de como te fue. Si tienes dudas sobre que hacer cuando te contestan la pregunta, puedes leer este link: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers